# how to know request already download completed?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to know or a report about completed request or download? currently i only can get if a url can be request and in progress by return object json status response 200. but it not accurates to do action after that response. algorithm is client request a file to server. server response with json object with property size request file. then in client browser get response status and compare in local currently size download in local byte by byte with json object size property that return by server. if byte match than do something.

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1/images/tileset.png')
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

Comment: This might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure that the two files -on internet and the local file- are the same, hashing will be better!

You should first return the response then console it.

```js
fetch('http://127.0.0.1/images/tileset.png')
  .then(function(myJson) {
    return myJson.blob();
  }).then((myJson)=>console.log(myJson.size));
```

Comment: i get error **Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0**

Comment: I edited it, this code will console the size of the image, this will work with you but first make sure that the image is valid! @daivdrush

Comment: ok, it's work. but as i think maybe it don't need server compare for quick result. cause it's not realtime to output currently download byte  as i want to make progress loading for assets loading.

Comment: can it possible to make it realtime output currently download byte in console?

Comment: Can you explain in more details?

Comment: cause i stuck if i refresh with setInterval i think the request will restart forever.

Comment: do you ever play games and when change map it will loading a resource for next map. ex. i have 3 file with different bytes. i make a index each file with size and sum the total bytes. the progress loading will output file name and progress download with data bytes in % real time..

Comment: if i play with setInterval i get status partial download 206. is there a way to know location when progress download?

Comment: I think [this tweet](https://twitter.com/umaar/status/917789464658890753) is related to your question

Comment: but it miss output name file when progress download. but i will learn from this code first.